# Trouble with showing name of the product because of the aggregates in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have trouble writing a query that will print or show the most expensive product that was bought from the specific town. So I have 2 tables, `ORDER1` and `Customer`.

In `ORDER1`, we have columns `OrderID`, `CustomerID`, `OrderDate`, `Price`, `ProductName`.

In `Customer` we have columns `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `City`.

And this is what I have so far but it is not working

```
SELECT ORDER1.ProductName
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN ORDER1 ON Customer.CustomerID = ORDER1.CustomerID
WHERE  Customer.City = 'Beograd'
HAVING MAX(ORDER1.Price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that doesn't do what you want.  Instead `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ORDER1.ProductName
FROM Customer INNER JOIN
     ORDER1
     ON Customer.CustomerID = ORDER1.CustomerID
WHERE  Customer.City = 'Beograd'
ORDER BY ORDER1.Price DESC;
```

You can include additional columns as well.

Note:  If there are ties, this will return all tied rows.

Comment: could you explain to me what is this in brackets (1) it reffers to something or, and access is telling me that  i am using reserved word or the argument name is misspelled but that is impossible.

Comment: It is correct just use top 1 without brackets. Thanks